# Mongo regex index matching - multiple start strings

Tags: regex, mongodb, indexing

I want to match multiple start strings in mongo.  explain() shows that it's using the indexedfield index for this query:

```
db.mycol.find({indexedfield:/^startstring/,nonindexedfield:/somesubstring/});
```

However, the following query for multiple start strings is really slow.  When I run explain I get an error.  Judging by the faults I can see in mongostat (7k a second) it's scanning the entire collection.  It's also alternating between 0% locked and 90-95% locked every few seconds.

```
db.mycol.find({indexedfield:/^(startstring1|startstring2)/,nonindexedfield:/somesubstring/}).explain();

JavaScript execution failed: error: { "$err" : "assertion src/mongo/db/key.cpp:421" } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:L128
```

Can anyone shed some light on how I can do this or what is causing the explain error?

**UPDATE - more info**

Ok, so I managed to get explain to work on the more complex query by limiting the number of results.  The difference is this:

For a single substring, "^/BA1/" (yes it's postcodes)

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor pc_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 10,
"nscannedObjects" : 10,
"nscanned" : 10,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 19,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 19,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 0,
"indexBounds" : {
    "indexedfield" : [
        [
            "BA1",
            "BA2"
        ],
        [
            /^BA1/,
            /^BA1/
        ]
    ]
}
```

For multiple substrings "^(BA1|BA2)/"

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor pc_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 10,
"nscannedObjects" : 10,
"nscanned" : 1075276,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1075285,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 2150551,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 5,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 4596,
"indexBounds" : {
    "indexedfield" : [
        [
            "",
            {

            }
        ],
        [
            /^(BA1|BA2)/,
            /^(BA1|BA2)/
        ]
    ]
}
```

which doesn't look very good.

Comment: Maybe you should try $or operator instead?

Comment: Or working great, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

$or solves the problem in terms of using the indexes (thanks EddieJamsession).  Queries are now lightening fast.

```
db.mycoll.find({$or: [{indexedfield:/^startstring1/},{indexedfield:/^startstring2/],nonindexedfield:/somesubstring/})
```

However, I would still like to do this with a regex if possible so I'm leaving the question open.  Not least because I now have to refactor my application to take these types of queries into account.